# Makefile:650: recipe for target 'honeyd.o' failed

Tags: honeypot

This is the problem I have been facing while installing Honeyd on my debian distro. Please suggest me some solutons. ./configure is successfuly competed but while calling make, this problem has arised.

```
root@kali:~/honeyd-1.5c# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I./compat/libdnet -I./compat -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/pcap -I/usr/include     -O2 -Wall -g -DPATH_HONEYDINCLUDE="\"/usr/local/include/honeyd\"" -DPATH_HONEYDDATA="\"/usr/local/share/honeyd\"" -DPATH_HONEYDLIB="\"/usr/local/lib/honeyd\"" -DHONEYD_PLUGINS_DECLARE="" -DHONEYD_PLUGINS="" -DPATH_RRDTOOL="\"/usr/bin/rrdtool\"" -c -o honeyd.c
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
Makefile:650: recipe for target 'honeyd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [honeyd.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Makefile:1022: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Makefile:509: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
root@kali:~/honeyd-1.5c# gedit Makefile
root@kali:~/honeyd-1.5c# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Making all in .
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I./compat/libdnet -I./compat -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/pcap -I/usr/include     -O2 -Wall -g -DPATH_HONEYDINCLUDE="\"/usr/local/include/honeyd\"" -DPATH_HONEYDDATA="\"/usr/local/share/honeyd\"" -DPATH_HONEYDLIB="\"/usr/local/lib/honeyd\"" -DHONEYD_PLUGINS_DECLARE="" -DHONEYD_PLUGINS="" -DPATH_RRDTOOL="\"/usr/bin/rrdtool\"" -c honeyd.c
In file included from /usr/local/include/event.h:77:0,
                 from honeyd.c:73:
tagging.h:89:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void encode_int(struct evbuffer *evbuf, uint32_t number);
      ^
tagging.h:89:6: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 void encode_int(struct evbuffer *evbuf, uint32_t number);
      ^
In file included from stats.h:36:0,
                 from honeyd.c:98:
./compat/sha1.h:23:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__minbytes__,2,64)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:23:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
./compat/sha1.h:26:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__string__,2,3)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:28:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__minbytes__,1,20)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:30:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__minbytes__,2,41)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:32:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__minbytes__,2,41)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:35:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
   __attribute__((__bounded__(__minbytes__,3,41)));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./compat/sha1.h:35:3: warning: ‘__bounded__’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
Makefile:650: recipe for target 'honeyd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [honeyd.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Makefile:1022: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/honeyd-1.5c'
Makefile:509: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Include the whole error.

Comment: Full error has been updated above in the post. Please help me solve those errors. Thank you for your reply.